# Disable ctrl + mouse scroll on a webpage

Tags: jquery, scroll, ctrl

How can I disable CTRL + mouse scroll on web page with jquery?

I want to disable zoom in and zoom out on my web page!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do this :

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) 
{
    if((event.keyCode == 107 && event.ctrlKey == true) || (event.keyCode == 109 && event.ctrlKey == true))
    {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }

    $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) 
    {
        if(event.ctrlKey == true)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

This will only work for Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It will not work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tested your script on newest Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox and IE. It seems to be working only with Firefox and IE. That will do the job just right :)

Comment: There might be a problem with the keycodes. Please check the keycodes for particular browser

Comment: This doesn't stop CTRL+- OR CTRL++

Comment: Works perfect on the Firefox! Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

Instead, you should design your page to support zoom.

Comment: I've seen lately some pages.. that just do nothing on Ctrl + mouse.. How can you explain me that? My apologies - doesn't have any example at the moment.

Comment: I realize that this answer is old but I can confirm that `e.preventDefault()` works in major browsers. It prevent the default zoom behaviour so you can implement your own zoom (or something else entirely). Of course you can not prevent someone from zooming in using the menu options, but you can prevent ctrl+scroll.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this, i've tested on chrome、filefox and ie. it work well

```js
(function () {

        /**
         * Main stopscrollwheelzoom constructor
         */
        let SSWZ = function () {

            /**
             * Handler for scroll- control must be pressed.
             * @param e
             */
            this.keyScrollHandler = function (e) {
                if (e.ctrlKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        if (window === top) {
            let sswz = new SSWZ();
            window.addEventListener('wheel', sswz.keyScrollHandler, { passive: false });
        }

    })();
```